# Calculating a fibonacci chart

Tags: c#, console, console-application

Im writing a program for my cs class and this is what i came up with. The issue is that my babies and adults columns are switched. I understand that I could just switch them when i display them but that doesnt help me understand how it works. Maybe i just dont understand the logic behind it....

There is a picture to show what it is suppose to look like.

```
        int adult = 1;
        int baby = 0;
        int total = 1;
        int month = 0;


        WriteLine("Table of rabbit population, in pairs.\n");
        WriteLine("Month\tAdults\tBabies\tTotal");


        do
        {
            month++;

            int temp = adult;                

            adult = baby;
            baby = temp + adult;


            total = adult + baby;

            WriteLine($"{month}\t{adult}\t{baby}\t{total}");
        } while (total < 500);

        WriteLine("\n\n");

        WriteLine($"Will run out of cages in month {month}\n\n");

        Write("Press any key to continue ... ");
```

[This is what the program is suppose to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sko5e.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, they're "switched" as you say because you do this:

```
int temp = adult;                

adult = baby;
baby = temp + adult;
```

You are creating a temporary variable and assigning the value of `adult` to it, then you're assigning the value of `baby` to the `adult` variable.  Switched.

Comment: Ive tried switching the adult and baby variables and that didnt work, or maybe im not understanding what you are saying.